# Insert function and program execution failed

Tags: python

I designed a small python program
I hope to achieve the following effects through the for loop and insert function

```py
Please enter the deposit on day 1: 40
Please enter the deposit on day 2: 70
Please enter the deposit on day 3: 89
Please enter the deposit on day 4: 489
Please enter the deposit on day 5: 39
Please enter the deposit on day 6: 48
Please enter the deposit on day 7: 99
Total deposit: 874 dollar
```

Set the number of days between 1 and 7 through the for in range loop
And insert it through the insert function (please enter the deposit of day ():)
But my python program has not been able to execute smoothly
My code:

```py
mey=list()
sum1=0
while True:
   moy=int(input("Please enter the deposit of the first day:"))
for moc in range(1,7):
     moy.insert(moc,4)
     if moc==7:
        break
        sum1+=moy
         print("Total deposit:",str(sum1),"dollar")
```

I hope you can give some assistance and guidance,
Thank you everyone

Comment: Please use meaningful variable names, not nonsense like `mey` and `moc`.

Comment: There's no need for `if moc == 7: break`, the loop will stop automatically when it gets to the end of the range.

Comment: And `moc == 7` will never be true, because `range()` doesn't include the second number.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a for loop like this

```
suml = 0
for _ in range(1,8):
    if _ in [4,5,7]:
        suml += int(input("Please enter the {}th day deposit: ".format(_)))
    else:
        suml += int(input("Please enter the deposit on day {}: ".format(_)))
print("Total deposit:",str(suml),"dollar")
```

Shortened version using generators:

```
print("Total deposit:",str(sum(int(input("Please enter the {}th day deposit: ".format(_))) if _ in [4,5,7] else int(input("Please enter the deposit on day {}: ".format(_))) for _ in range(1,8))),"dollar")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go;

```
sum = 0
for i in range(7):
    moy = int(input(f'Please enter the deposit for day{i + 1}: '))
    sum += moy

print(f'total deposit: ${sum}')
```

Comment: Did you notice the differences, in some cases (for 4,5,7) it needed to print like 4th,5th or 7th, see my answer

Comment: Check my answer. I am simply printing Day 1, day2 etc which is correct. There is no need of adding 'th' for higher numbers.

Comment: But does it really match the OP expected output? Read the upper part of the question.

Comment: The main part is he wants to get the set of inputs and the total.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain that that by this simple code;

**Code Syntax**

> *According to `Python 3.8`*

```
def deposit (days):
    aList = []
    for x in range(1, days+1):
        deposit = float(input(f"please, Enter your deposit for day {x}: "))
        aList.append(deposit)
    return print(f"Your total deposit in ({days}) days is:  ${sum(aList)}")


days = int(input("Enter how many days do you want to deposit: "))

deposit (days)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter how many days do you want to deposit: 3
please, Enter your deposit for day 1: 5.6
please, Enter your deposit for day 2: 5.4
please, Enter your deposit for day 3: 5
Your total deposit in (3) days is:  $16.0

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Btw, you can also make this `alList` as `global aList` so if you want to withdraw from the stored data, the data being minused from the total amount of money. Or another idea. You can also make `dic` instead of `list` so, you can edit specific day whenever you want and Insert all the data into `.txt` file operating the data by it using **python read & write** utility. It seems to be like a wallet for you calculate and exchange every time the amount you want beside a report for your deposit and withdraw processes.